# Update state value after another fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I Have tow APi's.

First one returned me a list of persons, and each person has hobbies witch are numbers.

`0:
hobby: (3) [28, 12, 16]
id: 233 
Name: John`

The second api returned me  an array with all hobbies

```
 hobbies:[
0: {id: 28, name: "Football"}
1: {id: 12, name: "Reading"}
2: {id: 16, name: "Dancing"}
]
```

now i have to see if the numbers of person.hobby are equal with the id of hobbies i have to update the state with the name of the hobbies.

And i need to have something like this:

`0:
hobby: (3) ["Football", "Reading", "Dancing"]
id: 233 
Name: John`

i have this state

`this.state = {
      results: [],
      hobbies: []
    };`

and my display

```
{results
        .map(person => (
          <div key={movie.id} className="person -holder">
            <p>{person.name}</p>
            <p>{person.hobbies}</p>// but here it display the numbers
          </div>
        ))}
```

How i can display Hobby from hobbies list?

Comment: Wrap the fetch with a promise or use async/await, and then setState with the value.

Comment: Do you mean that your second fetch is dependent on the first one and you won't get the hobbies? Or do you have trouble displaying hobbies? Can you please edit you question and make it more clear by adding more description/code? Thanks.

Comment: They are not dependent of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a second map to take care of the hobbies and then filter the results. Of course there are other ways to do this as well.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: [
        {
          hobby: [28, 12, 16],
          id: 233,
          Name: 'John'
        },
        {
          hobby: [12, 28],
          id: 100,
          Name: 'Andy'
        }
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {id: 28, name: "Football"},
        {id: 12, name: "Reading"},
        {id: 16, name: "Dancing"}
      ]
    };    
  }

   render() {
    return ( 
        this.state.results.map(person =>
        (
          <div key={person.id}>
            <p>{person.Name}</p>
            <div>{person.hobby.map(hobby => (
            <div key={hobby}>
              {this.state.hobbies.filter(h => h.id === hobby)[0].name}
            </div>
            ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          )
        )
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root" />
```